# How to execute multiple async functions depending on each other?

Tags: javascript, async-await, geocoding, ecmascript-2017

it seems I understand the behavior of async/ await, but now-now i am deeply stuck with my problem and cant solve it.
I am trying to create weather app and so I need to request the latitude and longitude first, then getting that info to send a request to weather API and get the forecast. As it's said in google documentation

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous since the Google Maps API needs to make a call to an external server.

So I am trying to use async/await to handle it.

```
import Search from './models/Search';
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
import { elements } from './views/base';

/*
* Search controller
*/

const state = {

};

const controlSearch = async () => {
  const query = searchView.getInput();

  if (query) {
    state.forecast = new Search(query);

    try {
      await state.forecast.codeAddress();
      await state.forecast.getForecast(state.forecast);
      console.log(state);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  controlSearch();
});
```

this is my controller . In the bottom i have put eventListener to form , which the user will use to search the city and then get it's forecast.

This is my Search model

```
import { key, proxy } from '../config';

export default class Search {
  constructor(query) {
    this.query = query;
  }

  codeAddress() {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ address: this.query }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude, 'lat long');
      }
    });
  }

  async getForecast(geometry) {
    console.log(geometry, 'geometry');
    const result = await fetch(`${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${key}/${geometry.latitude},${geometry.longitude}`);
    const forecast = await result.json();
    forecast.then((res) => {
      this.forecast = res;
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that when requesting to the darkSky API , the geometry.latitude and geometry longitude are undefined.

> How can i handle this problem ?

Comment: `codeAddress` doesn't `await` anything or return something to be `await`ed.  It closes immediately even if the `geocode` isn't done yet.

Comment: @zero298 So you mean to make codeAddress async/await ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`codeAddress` doesn't `await` anything or return something to be `await`ed.  It closes immediately even if the `geocode` isn't done yet.  Have it return a `Promise` that can be `await`ed.

```js
codeAddress() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      address: this.query
    }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude, 'lat long');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

---

Unfortunately, you will need to manually return a `Promise` since the [`Geocoder.geocode()` API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder#Geocoder.geocode) only follows a callback style of asynchronization and `await` will only wait on `.then()`-ables (like a `Promise`).

Comment: Yes , this works for me .Thanks a lot . Is there a way to solve it without Promise ?

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan See my edit.  `Promise` is probably the cleanest way to do this given `geocode`'s API.

Answer (score 0):

`codeAddress` is async (because the response is handled in a callback), but you are not treating it as async. Try this:

```
async codeAddress() {
  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    geocoder.geocode({ address: this.query }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude, 'lat long');
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

There are certainly other ways to convert an function with a callback to an async.

Comment: why `async` if not `await`-ing anything?